# How can I make my Retrofit model class handle NULL attributes?

Tags: android, json, gson, realm, retrofit2

I have this model class that stores the JSON objects from my API calls with Retrofit.

```
// Java
public class SampleClass extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private List<String> value;

}

// Json
{
    "id":1,
    "value":["one", "two"]
}
```

There are cases where the JSON objects won't have `values` and will appear like this.

```
{
    "id":2,
    "value":null
}
```

When this happens, I get this exception.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NULL
```

How can I handle this such that the `value` field for the Java object defaults to `null`?

EDIT: Note that I use this with Retrofit so it works like this.

```
    // Call to API
    Call<SampleClass> call = apiService.getSampleClass();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SampleClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SampleClass> call, Response<SampleClass> response) {
            // API Call was successful
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            // Logging t.toString() shows the error above.
        }
    });
```

The call always lands in `onFailure` if a field is NULL.

Comment: Your Retrofit API interface doesn't represent the actual response type (you wait for list and you get an object)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sorry, I just used a SampleClass to show the gist of my problem. I adjusted it.

Comment: Hello. Were you able to handle them? I may please know how you overcome it? I am having same issue. Thank you

Comment: @GulbalaSalamov No, sorry. I ended up asking the API guys to just send empty arrays for that case instead of null.

Comment: @IsaiahJ Thank you very much I'll consider this option too when needed